# Start an existing docker ubuntu container

Tags: docker

A related question & answer on  [How to start a docker container (ubuntu image)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985741/how-to-start-a-docker-container-ubuntu-image) suggest using `docker run -it ubuntu` to start a ubuntu container and connect to it. However the run command creates and starts a new ubuntu container.

How do we start an existing docker container (ubuntu image) given it's `CONTAINER_ID` without creating a new container?

Example:

`docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
9f297d02f419        ubuntu              "/bin/bash"         3 seconds ago        Exited (0) 1 seconds ago                            cranky_wilson
```

How do we start `9f297d02f419` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can start the stopped container using docker start command -

eg:
docker start 9f297d02f419

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't seem to work on ubuntu container.

Comment: In this case it's starting but then stopping straight away. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just use *run* on the Ubuntu image it will start a container that's running no command, which will immediately stop. You can *docker start* it but it will stop again. You can see it with *docker ps -a*.

The accepted answer in that question is very old and not very good. If you run that command on the current Docker version you get an error *No command specified*!

What you need to do is tell that container to run a command:

*docker run ubuntu date*

Will run a container from the image, run the *date* command, then exit. If you want to keep it running indefinitely, try something like:

*docker run -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null*

You should see that the container is now running. The -d makes it run in the background, otherwise it will occupy your shell. And the final piece of the puzzle: since we have a container now that's configured to run a command, you can use *docker ps* to find its ID, and you can *docker stop* and *docker start* it at will.